# Extracting Age values from text to create new column in pandas

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset as below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([["Sam is 5", 2000],["John is 3 years and 6 months",1200],["Jack is 4.5 years",7000],["Shane is 25 years old",2000]], columns = ['texts','amount'])

print(df)

    texts                          amount
0   Sam is 5                        2000
1   John is 3 years and 6 months    1200
2   Jack is 4.5 years               7000
3   Shane is 25 years old           2000
```

I want to extract Age values from `df['texts']` and use it to calculate new column `df['value']`.

```
df['value'] = df['amount'] / val
```

where val is numeric values from `df['texts']`

Here's my code

```
val = df['texts'].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d*)', expand=False).astype(float)
df['value'] = df['amount']/val
print(df)
```

output:

```
    texts                          amount     value
0   Sam is 5                       2000     400.000000
1   John is 3 years and 6 months   1200     400.000000
2   Jack is 4.5 years              7000     1555.555556
3   Shane is 25 years old          2000     80.000000
```

Expected Output:

```
    texts                          amount     value
0   Sam is 5                       2000     400.000000
1   John is 3 years and 6 months   1200     342.85
2   Jack is 4.5 years              7000     1555.555556
3   Shane is 25 years old          2000     80.000000
```

The issue in above code is I am not able to figure out how can I convert 3 years 6 months into 3.5 years.

**Additional Info**: Text column contains only Age values that too in order Years and months.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: 3 years and 6 months is _not_ 3.6 years.

Comment: I feel that you should be storing an absolute figure for each person, e.g. the birthday, and then calculating based on this.

Comment: @DyZ it is 3.5 years.

Comment: And your expression returns 3.0 because it ignores the "6 months." You need a regex like `'(\d+)(:?\.\d*)?\D+(\d*)'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

*Notice: If no years and months text then solution count with years*

```
#extract all first numbers
a = df['texts'].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d*)', expand=False).astype(float)
#extract years only
b = df['texts'].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d*)\s+years', expand=False).astype(float)
#replace NaNs by a
y = b.combine_first(a)
print(y)
0     5.0
1     3.0
2     4.5
3    25.0
Name: texts, dtype: float64

#extract months only
m = df['texts'].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d*)\s+months', expand=False).astype(float) / 12
print (m)
0    NaN
1    0.5
2    NaN
3    NaN
Name: texts, dtype: float64

#add together
val = y.add(m, fill_value=0)
print (val)
0     5.0
1     3.5
2     4.5
3    25.0
Name: texts, dtype: float64
```

---

```
df['value'] = df['amount']/val
print (df)
                          texts  amount        value
0                      Sam is 5    2000   400.000000
1  John is 3 years and 6 months    1200   342.857143
2             Jack is 4.5 years    7000  1555.555556
3         Shane is 25 years old    2000    80.000000
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.